# Delphi Parameterised Query won't work

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm only a beginner in learning to use Parameterised Queries as I used to do a lot of concatentating before.  I've been trying to get this query below to work. It is a simple 'Book' table, with a field called 'BookTitle'. I have a simple textbox where I invite the user to enter any title...and it should run the query below to find if that book exists.  Below is my code that, when run, manages to compile. However, when an entry into the textbox is added and the *button to run the query is pressed*, a Debugger Exception Notification appears with the following statement.

> Debugger Exception Notification: Project Project1.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another'.

I then have the option to press 'Break' or 'Continue'.  If I press 'Break', the line:

```
qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').DataType := ftString;
```

is filled with a purple/red colour (not sure what this means?).

That said, if I press 'Continue', the program will work as expected, and will continue to do so.  Here is the code i've been testing.

```
procedure TForm4.btnRunQueryClick(Sender: TObject);
var BookEntry:string;
begin
 BookEntry:=edtBookTitle.Text;
 qbook.SQL.Text:='SELECT BookTitle FROM Book WHERE BookTitle = :BookTitle';
 qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').DataType := ftString;
 qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').Value := BookEntry;
 qbook.Open;
end;
```

Further points to note: The components in my Delphi form are as follows
a TADOQuery named 'qbook',
a TDataSource, 
a TDBGrid, 
aTEdit into which the user enters their desired search criteria and 
a TButton that once pressed, initiates the query.

With regards to the database, it is:
a MySQL database (Community Edition)
a table named 'Book', where BookID is the PK and is of INT data type.
a field entitled 'BookTitle' which i've set as VARCHAR(35). It is not part of the key. However, it is in the BookTitle field, that i want to apply my query.

Comment: Have you checked that `qbook`'s connection is set correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gerry. I checked the connection for qbook, that is, the connection string property and clicked on 'Build', and then 'Test Connection' and it says 'Test Connection Succeeded'. So, it appears there is not issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: This answer was posted based on the original code in the question, which has been edited to match what is in my answer. See the question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28465133/revisions) for the first version of the question on which my answer was based.

The solution you saw in the other post was correct; it was just for a standard `TQuery` and not `TADOQuery`. `TADOQuery` requires a couple of minor syntax changes:

- Use `Parameters.ParamByName()` instead of `Parameters`
- Set a `DataType` for each parameter before using it
- Use `.Value` instead of `.AsString`

Here's a corrected version of your code (which also includes setting a value for `BookTitle` before using it.

```
procedure TForm4.btnRunQueryClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  BookEntry:string;
begin
  BookEntry := 'Some book title';   // or QueryEdit.Text or whatever

  qbook.SQL.Text:='SELECT BookTitle FROM Book WHERE BookTitle = :BookTitle';
  qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').DataType := ftString;
  qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').Value := BookEntry;
  qbook.Open;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. It compiles now, however,  getting the following compiler message... " 'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another'. "   If i press continue, sure enough, the result is shown in my textbox.

Comment: Um, a compiler message like that would not allow your program to run, so I'm not sure how that's possible. It would also tell you exactly what line is causing the error. What *exact* message are you getting, and *exactly* when?

Comment: Here is the complete message which appears on the click event of the button which is to run the code.   Debugger Exception Notification:
Project1.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another'.    When i press break, the line   qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').Value:=BookEntry;  is in read.

Comment: That implies that the SQL parameter does not accept a `string` value as input.  What is the data type of the `BookTitle` column?

Comment: @user3396486 Can you provide `Book` table creation script here?

Comment: In mySQL the field entitled BookTitle is VARCHAR(45) type

Comment: -- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `library_db`.`book`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `library_db`.`book` (
  `BookID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BookTitle` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `BookAuthor` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `DatePublished` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

Comment: Anothe suggestion: `qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').DataType := ftString;` before assigning parameter value (not sure tat is works, may be  `qbook.Parameters[0].DataType` will..)

Comment: IF this is what you mean.... qbook.SQL.Text:='SELECT BookTitle FROM Book WHERE BookTitle = :BookTitle';
 qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').Value:=ftString;
 BookEntry:=edtBookTitle.Text;
 qbook.Open;      ....i'm still encountering the same error.

Comment: @user3396486 I mean: `qbook.SQL.Text:='SELECT BookTitle FROM Book WHERE BookTitle = :BookTitle'; qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').DataType := ftString; qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').Value :=edtBookTitle.Text; qbook.Open;`

Comment: Oh dear....compiler now throwing the following up:  "Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation".

Comment: It is much better then previous error. So in which line this error is occurred?

Comment: The debugger flashes up this line in red/purple:   qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle').DataType := ftString;

Comment: @user3396486 So qbook.Parameters.ParamByName('BookTitle') have no DataType field?

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but still getting same error as before.  I guess it should not be as complicated as this.... parameterised queries?

Comment: `qbook` - just try to put it on the form at design time and try to open and play with pARAMETERS. Sorry, i am offlne.

Comment: @user3396486: You really need to be clear. The *compiler* does not throw up errors like "Application uses a value of the wrong type", and the *debugger* does not *flash up* anything in red/purple.  There's a big difference between *the compiler* and a *runtime exception* and "the debugger". I've edited my answer to include an example of how to set the Parameter.DataType, and it successfully compiles in Delphi 2007 and Delphi XE7 using the standard `TADOQuery`.

Comment: @Abelisto: Please stop asking the poster to provide code in the comments here, and ask for them to be edited into the question instead. They're impossible to format (or read) when jammed into a comment, they add tons of clutter and noise, and they can't be seen by future readers clearly as part of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Abelisto: The poster said that `Parameters.ParamByName()` compiled, and that's syntax for TADOQuery. A standard `TQuery` uses `Query.ParamByName`, not `Query.Parameters.ParamByName`, and the poster said that the first didn't work (see the third code snippet in the question). So it must be a `TADOQuery`.

Comment: @Ken: thanks, i noted your edits. It is the debugger which throws up the 'Debugger Exception Notification'...alluded to earlier.

Comment: @user3396486: A **Debugger Exception** is much different than **flashes up this line in red/purple**. A debugger exception is a runtime exception, which is not a compiler message either. As I said, you need to be clear about what you're saying and where the problem is located. If your `BookTitle` column (field) is a string type, the code should work as I posted it. If it's something else, **edit your question** and provide that information there so people can see it. You haven't indicated what components or database you're using at all, so we're having to just guess here.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question, and to the best of my ability, given accurate information about the scenario.

Answer (score -1):

I have never known a string type query parameter need the datatype or whatever set, I would simply remove any reference to the datatype.

After all, if it hurts when you bang your head on a wall, just stop banging it.

Comment: The line for setting `DataType` was added after the poster complained that it didn't  work without it. See the comments below my answer, as well as the revision history of that answer. This also isn't an answer to the question asked; it's more of a comment, and should be posted as one.